# Regex: How to match all uppercase characters of non-ascii string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have strings like `Japan Company`, `Chinese Company`, and this regex `/([A-Z])/g` to get all uppercase characters then joining the result to make an emission of them. But when the input string is not in English letters then the regex does not work.

```
let string = "Japan Company";
console.log(string.match(/[A-Z]/g).join('')); // JC
```

But when I have a string like `日本の会社`

```
let string = "日本の会社";
console.log(string.match(/[A-Z]/g).join(''));
```

This throws an exception as the result of the `string.match(/[A-Z]/g)` is `null`.

As I am trying to make elision to these strings and hieroglyphs do not have uppercases, the regex should match only first characters of each word where words are separated by spaces.

##### What generic regex should I use for this?

Something like POSIX's `[:upper:]` but this does not work for JavaScript regex engine.

Comment: I could be wrong about this, but as far as I know there are no uppercase letters in chinese. What result were you expecting to get?

Comment: Oh, right I forgot what I am expecting as a result of the Chinese string, let me edit my question

Comment: So, you want to get the unchanged string as a result if it has no uppercase letters?

Comment: Regarding your edit, do you also want to get the first letter of each word if it's all lowercase in latin characters? For example, do you want `japan company` to return `jc`?

Comment: Try `(string.match(/\b[A-Z]/ig) || string.match(/(?<!\S)\S/g) || [string]).join('').toUpperCase()`, too.

Comment: @asportnoy `japan company` can return `JC` as it is an elision and must be uppercase

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I see your point but is there a generic regex to do that the same thing

Comment: What do you mean by "generic" here? I think you need a *working* regex. However, a regex itself cannot turn a string to upper case.

Comment: Yes, but you are using `/\b[A-Z]/ig` and `/(?<!\S)\S/g`. And I am asking is there a common one?

Comment: `/(?<!\S)\S/g` will do then, if you only care to get the first non-whitespace chars after start of string/whitespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
(string.match(/(?<!\S)\S/g) || [string]).join('')
```

See the JavaScript demo:

```js
const strings = ["Japan Company", "japan company", "日本の会社"];
for (const string of strings) {
    console.log(string, '=>', (string.match(/(?<!\S)\S/g) || [string]).join('').toUpperCase())
}
```

The `(?<!\S)\S` regex matches a non-whitespace char at the start of string or after a whitespace char.

A Safari, non-lookbehind, pattern:

```js
var strings = ["Japan Company", "japan company", "日本の会社"];
for (var i=0; i<strings.length; i++) {
    var m = strings[i].match(/(?:^|\s)(\S)/g)
    if (m === null) {
        console.log(strings[i], '=> ', strings[i])
    } else {
        console.log(strings[i], '=>', m.join('').replace(/\s+/g, '').toUpperCase())
    }
}
```

Comment: Great answer per question but 日 (day/sun) can't be used to shorthand 日本 (Japan).  Same issue in Chinese.

Comment: @AutomateThis This will be probably solved with Japanese / Chinese tokenizers, regex would not help here.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, I think this should do what you want.

```js
function getUppercaseLetters(string) {
    // Find uppercase letters in the string
    let matches = string.match(/[A-Z]/g);
    // If there are no uppercase letters, get the first letter of each word
    if (!matches) matches = string.split(" ").map(word => word[0]);
    // If there are still no matches, return an empty string. This should prevent against any edge cases.
    if (!matches) return "";
    // Join the array elements and make it uppercase.
    return matches.join("").toUpperCase();
}
```